# Unmet dependencies when trying to install PostgreSQL with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, postgresql, wget

I am trying to install postgresql in ubuntu 20.04, but facing unment dependicies issue.

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is to be installed
Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After these error, i run `sudo apt--fix-broken install`but, i facing same issue again.

Comment: What do you mean you tried to install postgresql via wget? Use apt to install postgresql.

Comment: Are you trying to install PostgreSQL or MySQL? Your question says one, but the error says another. Did a previous attempt to install MySQL fail and now you're trying to put PostgreSQL on the machine?

Comment: @matigo, yes you right,first i am trying to install mysql but facing dependicies issue, then i decide to install postgresql,and also facing same issue.

Comment: The issue with the MySQL installation is that packages from two very different versions are being installed. You may want to address the MySQL situation first, *then* approach the PostgreSQL installation.

Comment: i have tried many solutions but no one worked,now i did not understand, how to solve it.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libmysqlclient21  mysql-common mysql-community-client-plugins` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1347884/edit).